# C# geoprocessing tool output file

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I'm trying to use file output parameter in arcobjects geoprocessing tool which will be used as rest service on ArcGis server 10.1

```
IGPParameterEdit3 outParam = new GPParameterClass();
outParam.DataType = (IGPDataType)new DEFileTypeClass();
outParam.Value = (IGPValue)new DEFileClass();
outParam.Direction = esriGPParameterDirection.esriGPParameterDirectionOutput;
outParam.ParameterType = esriGPParameterType.esriGPParameterTypeDerived;
outParam.DisplayName = "ResultFile";
outParam.Name = "outResultFile";
```

What i do know is how to access file if that is input parameter:

```
IGPParameter inFileParam = (IGPParameter)paramvalues.Element[inFileParamID];
IDEFile deFile = inFileParam.Value as IDEFile;
IDataElement dataElement = deFile as IDataElement;
string filePath = dataElement.CatalogPath;
```

But what I'm trying to figure out is how to set output file. At the moment some things i have tried is:

```
IGPParameter outFileParam = (IGPParameter)paramvalues.Element[outFileParamID];
IDEFile deFile = outFileParam.Value as IDEFile;
IPersistStream pStream = deFile as IPersistStream;

ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.FileStream fileStream = new ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem.FileStream();
fileStream.LoadFromFile(someFilePath);
IStream iStream = fileStream as IStream;
pStream.Load(iStream);
```

But last line throws COMException "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."